# How to parse a specific column or data without losing content from other columns/rows after parsing?

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have the following output to grep the value in this case "225". This value is actually a variable $pd so it could change depending on users input" It could be integer numbers or an alphanumeric character case-insensitive exact match. Example if value of variable is "225" then a "0225" or "11225" its not a valid output from the file Im reading it.

```
Input File:
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/2|DeviceX_4021|LG
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/3|Undiscoverable|Unkwn
10.20.225.10|2000-H1|1/1/5|DeviceZ_2050|LG
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_01225_|Kenmore
10.20.225.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_2250_|Kenmore

Desired Output File:
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore

If user input is "lg"; then it should output the line without not ignoring it because the input file has "lg" in uppercase. (This part is already fixed on the script).

Desired Output:
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/2|DeviceX_4021|LG
10.20.225.10|2000-H1|1/1/5|DeviceZ_2050|LG
```

Comment: It's always trivial to match the text you want but much harder to not match similar text that you don't want. Please [edit] your example to include lines where $4 contains  1225 and/or 2251 so we can see how those should be treated.

Comment: Oh yes; it needs to be an exact match but case insensitive if possible . That "225" could be a variable; or a constant as well. Im using "read" command to store the number or alphanumeric value to a variable named $pd . So I edited the awk answer with this: awk -F'|' -v n=$pd '$4 ~ n' file

Comment: Im still trying to find out how to make awk or gawk work with case-insensitive on that awk like. I used tolower ($0) and IGNORECASE=1 without success

Comment: If you ask a new question and include all of your requirements in the text and example then we can help you with that and the other things not addressed by your current question.

Comment: Found the solution: awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -F'|' -v n=$pd '$4 ~ n' file

Comment: That is definitely not the solution to the problem you've described in comments, it would only do case-insensitive matching in 1 awk variant when there's a trivial alternative that'd work in any awk, and it has other issues. If you'd like help, ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' -v n='225' '$4 ~ n' file
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore
```

or if you don't want a partial match (e.g. against `1225`) then one way is:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v n='225' '$4 ~ ("(^|[^0-9])" n "([^0-9]|$)")' file
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v n='225' '$4 ~ ("(^|_)" n "(_|$)")' file
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore
```

There are other possibilities too. The right solution depends on the requirements you haven't told us about and will pass or fail when using input other then you've shown us yet.

Comment: Thanks so much; with awk I was able to replace "225" into a variable like this: awk -F'|' -v n=$pd '$4 ~ n' file.txt

Comment: Storing the value in a variable is the easy part. Think about my comment under your question and what I said in my answer. If that's not clear consider this - if `pd` is `225` and an input line's $4 contains `DeviceZ_2250` should that line be printed or not? If it should then  the script in your comment is a reasonable approach, if it should not then the script in your comment is the wrong approach and you should look at the other scripts in my answer.

Comment: In that case; if device is 2250 then it should not be printed. It needs to be a perfect match; the only way it doesnt matter is if its a lower or upper case. Ex: if its looking a word "LG" and user inputs "lg" or "Lg" or "lG" it should match; but if its a number; it needs to be exact "225" as "225" and not "2250" or 0225".  Thanks!

Comment: You can see that none of that is discussed in your question or present in the example in your question for us to test with. We all answered the question you asked so please ask a new question and include all of those details in the text and in the example.

Answer (score 1):

`awk`

```
awk -F"|" -v var="[A-Za-z].225_" '$4 ~ var{print}'
```

`sed`

```
sed -n '/[A-Za-z].225./p'
```

`grep`

```
grep '[A-Za-z].225.'
```

**Output**

```
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore
```

Answer (score 0):

There's almost certainly an `awk` solution too, but in Perl it's this:

```
$ perl -aF'\|' -ne '$F[3] =~ 225 and print' < input
10.20.223.10|2000-H1|1/1/8|DeviceY_225_|Kenmore
```

- `-a`: Autosplit the input into array `@F`
- `-F'\|`: Set the autosplit delimiter to `|`
- `-n`: Run code for each line in the input file
- `-e`: Here's the code to run
- `$F[3]`: The 4th element of the autosplit array `@F`
- `=~`: Regex match
- `and print`: Print the input line if the regex matches

**Update:** You can get the string you're interested in from a command line parameter by assigning it in a `BEGIN` block.

```
$ perl -aF'\|' -ne 'BEGIN { $x = shift } $F[3] =~ $x and print' 225 < input
```

Comment: @JavierGonzalez: Arrays in Perl are zero-indexed. First element is $array[0], second is $array[1], etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. About the value of "225" in fact it could be any alphanimeric character; and it needs to be a variable. How can I replace that "225" into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^\([^|]*\|\)\{3\}[^|]*225/p' < input
```

Explanation:

- the `-n` option disables automatic output at the end of each `sed` cycle
- the pattern matches arbitrary contents of the first three (`\{3\}`) columns of data via the `\(`parenthesized`\)` pattern `[^|]*\|` -- any number of non-delmiter characters followed by the column delimiter
- it matches additional input at the beginning of the fourth column, but not spanning columns, with a similar subexpression: `[^|]*`
- then comes the literal text you want to match
- the `p` command after the pattern causes the line to be printed to `sed`'s output in the event that it matches the pattern

Comment: The sed works great; wondering; Im assuming {3\} is column 4; but why is a 3 and not a 4 there?

Comment: @JavierGonzalez, I have added an explanation, but in short, `\{3\}` is a repetition operator.  It says to match three copies of the preceding item, which is a run of text up to and including the column delimiter.  After three delimiters, you're looking at the fourth column.